# Lightswitch freezes on combobox (entity relationship)

Tags: c#, entity, visual-studio-lightswitch, freeze

After modeling and entity like this

Plans

- Id Integer
- Assignment Assignment (From Plans Many to Assignment One (Cascade delete))

Assignment

- Id Integer
- Plans Plans (From Plans Many to Assignment One (Cascade delete))
- Computed Property AssignmentId
- Some other properties and relationships (All many to one)

When I take the default details screen op Plans and run that screen. As soon as I click on Assignment with an existing assignment in place. Lightswitch freezes.

After manually adding a plan to the database whenever the screen is run it instantly freezes.

Anyone that has seen this sort of behaviour and knows what it causes?

Comment: It doesn't freeze when Assignment has no records.

Comment: It seems it crashes when the Summary Property points to a computed property.

Comment: After further investigation it turned out for some reason I can't link to a deeper node in the computed property. I eventually solved it by getting rid of the computed property and setting the value of that field on save. It's a field that shouldn't change that much eitherway.